# Why declaring method type in class raises syntax error in python?

Tags: python, class, types

[image]
From "LeetCode"  problem, It is the Solution class format with a certain method.
However, if I execute it with a simple return, It raises a syntax error like below. 
Why the parameter type declaration has the error that?  
Is this a clean format to write code?

[image]

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: Please don't post code as images...

Comment: You are likely running an older python version that doesn't support type annotations

Answer (score 0):

Python typings it's a feature that has been introduced from [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html), it's very likely that you are using a previous version if you get that error

Comment: Annotations for parameters were supported in 3.0 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), 3.5 added support for variable type hints.

Comment: Thank you a lot, let me get through the documentation from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a version of Python that doesn't support annotations (i.e. Python 2.7):

```
~ $ python2
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 17 2020, 18:29:03)
>>> def x(a: str):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def x(a: str):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
~ $ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26)
>>> def x(a: str):
...
```

Comment: I didn't expect my visual studio default setting to be version 2. I appreciate your answer AKX.